# Ansible error when I using an array style to inspect the host properties

Tags: ansible

I have a site.yml playbook, when I use this configuration:

```
- hosts: target
  tags:
    - setup_target
  tasks:
    - name: See some data
      debug: msg={{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][ansible_lsb].codename }}
```

Ansible report me an error:

```
PLAY [target] ***************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [target]

TASK: [See some data] ********************************************************* 
fatal: [target] => One or more undefined variables: dict object has no element {u'release': u'14.04', u'major_release': u'14', u'codename': u'trusty', u'id': u'Ubuntu', u'description': u'Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS'}

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/robe/site.retry

target                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

But if I use dot style, like this:

```
---
# The main playbook to deploy

# setup our database
- hosts: target
  tags:
    - setup_target
  tasks:
    - name: See some data
      debug: msg={{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_lsb.codename }}
```

The output is ok:

```
PLAY [target] ***************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [target]

TASK: [See some data] ********************************************************* 
ok: [target] => {
    "msg": "trusty"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
target                     : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Then, What is the different? For me, the both are equals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Then, What is the different? For me, the both are equals?

This comes down to how dicts/hashes work in Python- and by extension, how they work in jinja2 and Ansible.

If you have a dict called `data` and you want the value of the `foo` element, you access it like this:

```
data["foo"]
```

If you omit the quotes, you need to have a variable named foo.

```
data[foo] # does not work (so far)
```

jinja2 also lets you use the dot style:

```
data.foo
```

Let's pretend the value of the "foo" element is the number 42. These are all true:

```
data["foo"] = 42
data[foo] # does not work
data.foo = 42
```

Now, what if you have a variable named foo? In the following example we'll consider the value of the key 'foo' to still be 42, and 'bar' will be 13.

```
foo = "bar"
data["foo"] = 42
data[bar] = 13
data.foo = 42
```

To translate this to your original case, keep in mind that `inventory_hostname` and `ansible_lsb` are both **variables**, not **strings**. Even more confusing, ansible_lsb is a dictionary. That means your original bracketed style expands like this:

```
hostvars["inventory_hostname"][{u'release': u'14.04', u'major_release': u'14', u'codename': u'trusty', u'id': u'Ubuntu', u'description': u'Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS'}]["codename"]
```

oops. a dict as the key of a dict gets into recursive cannibalistic turtles.

Here's what your "dotted" style comes out to being.

```
hostvars["inventory_hostname"]["ansible_lsb"]["codename"]
```

that one can be translated slightly too, to make it slightly more clear:

```
lsb = hostvars["inventory_hostname"]["ansible_lsb"]
lsb["codename"]
```

That's obviously what you intended.

Comment: Upvoted, if only for the warning about recursive cannibalistic turtles. They're dangerous!